# Regex to Glob and vice-versa conversion

Tags: regex, go, glob

We have a requirement where we want to convert Regex to cloudfront supported Glob and vice-versa. Any suggestion how can we achieve that and first of all whether it's possible?especially from Regex to Glob, as I understand regex is kind of superset so it might not be possible to convert all the Regex to corresponding Glob?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert from a glob you would need to write a parser that split the pattern into an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). For example, the glob `*-{[0-9],draft}.docx` might parse to `[Anything(), "-", OneOf([Range("0", "9"), "draft"]), ".docx"]`.

Then you would walk the AST and output the equivalent regular expression for each node. For example, the rules you might use for this could be:

```
Anything()  -> .*
Range(x, y) -> [x-y]
OneOf(x, y) -> (x|y)
```

resulting in the regular expression `.*-([0-9]|draft).docx`.

That's not perfect, because you also have to remember to escape any special characters; `.` is a special character in regular expressions, so you should escape it, yielding finally `.*-([0-9]|draft)\.docx`.

Strictly speaking regular expression cannot all be translated to glob patterns. The [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) operation does not exist in globbing; the simple regular expression `a*` (i.e., any number of `a` characters) cannot be translated to a glob pattern.

I'm not sure what types of globs CloudFront supports (the documentation returned no hits for the term "glob"), but [here is some documentation on commonly-supported shell glob pattern wildcards](https://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm).

Here is a summarization of the some equivalent sequences:

| Glob Wildcard | Regular Expression | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `?` | `.` | Any single character |
| `*` | `.*` | Zero or more characters |
| `[a-z]` | `[a-z]` | Any character from the range |
| `[!a-m]` | `[^a-m]` | A character not in the range |
| `[a,b,c]` | `[abc]` | One of the given characters |
| `{cat,dog,bat}` | `(cat|dog|bat)` | One of the given options |
| `{*.tar,*.gz}` | `(.*\.tar|.*\.gz)` | One of the given options, considering nested wildcards |

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details and references really appreciate! Here is the link to Cloudfront supported pattern (path pattern section).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern

Comment: In this much simpler case of only `*` and `?` wildcards, without an escape character, you could something like `glob.escape_regex().replace('\\*', '.*').replace('\\?', '.')`

Comment: Yes thanks again, I was able to write conversion from Glob to Regex but had doubts about Regex to Glob conversion...